# Bring out the inner llama of a sentence

Tags: code-golf, subsequence

Your objective is to take input like

```
Pie is good.  I just ate a bunch of pies early this morning.  Actually, it was closer to the afternoon.  Mornings are good.
```

and create an array of the indexes of the string where the letters that make up the word "Llama" appear (one of each in order).  For example, let me show the letters pointed at with carets to show the indexes:

```
Pie is good.  I just ate a bunch of pies early this morning.  Actually, it was closer to the afternoon.  Mornings are good.
                                            ^                      ^        ^                            ^        ^
```

So the array would look like:

```
[44, 67, 76, 105, 114]
```

(If your application uses a indexing that's not 0-based, the numbers will look different.  That's fine.)

If the text has no llama, then the array should be empty, nil, null, or undefined.

Any code language is accepted.  This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) contest, so the least characters win!

Comment: Still, which letters should we choose? In your example, could we do {67, 68, 76, 91, 100} - both _l_'s of "actually"?

Comment: @Ypnypn Choose the first instances of the letters.  An l was found before, so it doesn't get the second l of actually

Comment: @TheWobbuffet You keep changing your username and picture. There was a time when you were "Doorknob" and had his picture. Now, your pic is a sheep. You should change it to a llama.

Comment: What about 0-based vs 1-based indexing? Can we just use the indexing used by our language or do all submissions have to conform to one convention (which one)?

Comment: @Quincunx The sheep says '42' on it!

Comment: @m.buettner I really don't care about that.  Whichever one you want.  Also, which programming languages use 1-based indexing? :P

Comment: @TheWobbuffet way too many maths oriented ones :-/ (Matlab, Mathematica, Julia, I don't know about R)... also Lua and Smalltalk. The only one of those relevant to code golfing would be Mathematica though, but probably not for string manipulation tasks.

Comment: Do you just want the function that does it or the whole program? Do you want the input/output code as well?

Comment: @m.buettner Oh, I see.  Math.

Comment: @malik A function that takes input and returns the array, or a variable in a function that can be changed by the programmer and a variable that is set to the array.

Comment: Your numbers are wrong btw, should be 44, 67, 76, 105, 114 (as you can see in several answers)

Comment: @aditsu Ok, edited.

Comment: @m.buettner What makes you think mathematica outperforms at golfing? Compared to MATLAB for instance?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin depends on the task (I know I've seen a few really concise Matlab answers on here), but Mathematica can be really useful for some tasks because it just has built-in support for so many high-level tasks like graph manipulation and combinatorics and image manipulation a d stuff... Also, try searching this site for "mathematica" and "matlab" ;)

Comment: @TheWobbuffet — AppleScript counts starting at 1. Like humans do, in fact.

Comment: @TheWobbuffet classic APL also starts at 1, although there is a flag to set it to 0. I come from a C background, so 0-indexing makes a lot of sense to me, but after learning APL I must admit that 1-indexing is very nice and overall more intuitive. You should give it a try!

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco So does my 7-year-old cousin who I can't convince he moves his monopoly guy one less amount of times

Comment: Is input guaranteed to only have 0 or 1 "llama"s?  If there are two or more llamas, correct output would just be indexes for the first?  Note sure I expect an answer given the age of this, but asking anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## CJam - 33

```
lel"llama"{1$#)_T+:T\@>}/;]___|=*
```

It gets the 1-based indexes (2 more bytes for 0-based)

Explanation:

`l` reads a line from the input (replace with `q` for whole input)
`el` converts to lowercase
`"llama"{...}/` executes the block for each "llama" letter
`1$` copies the current string
`#` finds the index of the letter
`)_` increments and duplicates
`T+:T` adds T (initially 0), updates T and leaves it on the stack
`\@` swaps items around, now we have current-T, index, string
`>` slices the string starting at the index
`;` pops the remaining string
`]` gathers the indexes in an array
At this point we have all the 1-based indexes; iff any letter was not found, the array will have duplicates.
`___` makes 3 more copies of the array
`|` (with 2 array copies) removes duplicates
`=` compares, resulting in 0 if there were duplicates or 1 if not
`*` multiplies the array 0 or 1 times accordingly

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Home/ for more info on the language. New to me.

Answer (score 12):

## Perl, 52 bytes

The solution is provided as function that takes the string as argument and returns a list of positions.

- One-based positions, case-sensitive search, without newlines: **52 bytes**

  ```perl
  sub l{pop=~/(l).*?(l).*?(a).*?(m).*?(a)/;@+[1..$#+]}
  ```

  The case-sensitive search returns an empty array in the example of the question, because after matching the first three letters the lowercase letter `m` is missing in the input text.
- Support of newlines: + 1 byte = **53 bytes**

  ```perl
  sub l{pop=~/(l).*?(l).*?(a).*?(m).*?(a)/s;@+[1..$#+]}
  ```

  The text can now span several lines.
- Case-insensitive search: + 1 byte = **54 bytes**

  ```perl
  sub l{pop=~/(l).*?(l).*?(a).*?(m).*?(a)/si;@+[1..$#+]}
  ```

  Now the example in the question reports a list of index positions,
  they are one-based numbers:

  ```
  [45 68 77 106 115]
  ```
- Zero-based positions: + 9 bytes = **63 bytes**

  ```perl
  sub l{pop=~/(l).*?(l).*?(a).*?(m).*?(a)/si;map{$_-1}@+[1..$#+]}
  ```

  Result for the example in the question:

  ```
  [44 67 76 105 114]
  ```

**Ungolfed:**

The latter variant includes more or less the other variants.

```perl
sub l {
    # pop() gets the last argument 
    pop() =~ /(l).*?(l).*?(a).*?(m).*?(a)/si;
    # the letters inbetween are matched against ".*?",
    # the non-greedy variant of ".*". Thus ".*?"
    # matches only as few as possible characters.
    # The modifier /i controls the case-sensitivity
    # and means ignore case. Without the case matters.
    # Modifier /s treats the string as single line,
    # even if it contains newlines.
    map { $_-1 }   # subtract 1 for zero-based positions
        @+[1..$#+]
    # Array @+ contains the end-positions of the last
    # submatches, and of the whole match in the first position.
    # Therefore the first value is sliced away.
    # @+ is available since Perl 5.6.
}

# test
my @result = l(<<"END_STR");
Pie is good.  I just ate a bunch of pies early this morning.  Actually, it was closer to the afternoon.  Mornings are good.
END_STR
print "[@result]\n";
```

Comment: This also assumes that the input is ASCII, or at least not full Unicode. Unless Perl's regexes correctly respect grapheme boundaries these days (they certainly did not back when I had the misfortune of using it.)

Comment: @Trejkaz: Unicode does not matter at all here: (a) "llama" is ASCII and its letters does not collide with any non-ASCII Unicode character or its byte representation in UTF-8. (b) With multi-byte encodings in mind, the term "index" in the question would be underspecified. Index can relate to the character position or the byte (storage) position. (c) Supporting any encoding with characters positions would mean, that the encoding should be known and needs to be provided as additional argument.

Comment: Your first two solutions print `[]` and the third prints `[    ]` for me (the longer ones work correctly). I'm running "perl, v5.8.8 built for msys-64int". Do you have a bug, or does it work on a different version of perl?

Comment: @TimS.: `[]` is correct for the first solution, `M` is not matched in a case-sensitive search. The question is quite unclear regarding case-sensitivity.

Comment: Ok, so `[]` is acceptable for the first two. But the first three solutions are still not working right for me: if you give it input that should return indexes, it returns `[    ]`

Comment: Here's a golfish example. It's based on your one-based, case-sensitive, without-newline code. `sub l{pop=~/(l).*?(l).*?(a).*?(m).*?(a)/;@+[1..$#+]};my@r=l("llama");print"[@r]\n";` And, actually, I can verify that it [works generally](http://ideone.com/q5Cf6h), just not for my version of Perl. So, don't worry about it, your solution is valid.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek even if you completely ignore *encodings* (because I was talking about the character set, technically) - if the last "a" you match is followed by a U+0308 combining diaresis then it is arguably no longer an "a" the same letter and shouldn't be considered a match. By the same token, if ä as a single character appears, that would *not* be considered a match, so I would say that in the presence of Unicode, this algorithm is at best inconsistent (and at worst, complete rubbish.)

Comment: @Trejkaz: `a` + U+308 in UTF-8 is the byte sequence 0x61 0xCC 0x88. And this is string `aÃà` in [Mac OS Roman](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/APPLE/ROMAN.TXT) and `a` would be correctly matched. The question does *not* specify an encoding. What do you expect from an *code golf* program to handle an unspecified and unknown encoding? Analyzing all thinkable and unthinkable encodings and calculate the result for each possible encoding assumption?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Irrespective of the encoding, an `ä` _should not_ match, because it is not an `a`. That's exactly the incorrect behaviour I am pointing out. I'm glad you have finally noticed the bug. :)

Comment: @Trejkaz: There is no bug, only an underspecified question.

Answer (score 12):

## sed, 299+1

Yes, sed can find a llama. No, sed can't do math. This is the longest answer so far, at 299+1 characters, because I had to teach sed to count.

This answer requires a sed with extended regular expressions (`sed -E` or `sed -r`). I used OpenBSD [sed(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sed&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current&arch=i386&format=html). Input is one string per line. (Therefore, the string may not contain a newline.) Output is a line of numbers, or nothing.

Usage (+1 character for `-r`):

```
$ echo 'All arms on all shoulders may ache.' | sed -rf llama.sed
1 2 12 26 30
```

Source code (299 characters):

```
s/%/z/g
s/(.*)[Aa]/\1%/
s/(.*)[Mm](.*%)/\1%\2/
s/(.*)[Aa]((.*%){2})/\1%\2/
s/(.*)[Ll]((.*%){3})/\1%\2/
s/(.*)[Ll]((.*%){4})/\1%\2/
/(.*%){5}/!d
s/[^%]/z/g
:w
s/(z*)%/\10 z\1/
s/z*$//
s/z0/1/
s/z1/2/
s/z2/3/
s/z3/4/
s/z4/5/
s/z5/6/
s/z6/7/
s/z7/8/
s/z8/9/
s/([0-9]z*)z9/z\10/g
s/(z*)z9/1\10/
/[%z]/bw
```

The program first replaces the llama with five `%`. (All `%` in this program are literal.) The first command `s/%/z/g` changes any `%` to `z` in the input line. The next five commands find the llama, so *All arms on all shoulders may ache.* becomes *A%% arms on %ll shoulders %ay %che.* Because each `.*` is greedy, I always finds the llama on the right: *llama llama* would become *llama %%%%%*. If I can't get five `%`, then `/(.*%){5}/!d` deletes the input line and skips the next commands.

`s/[^%]/z/g` changes every character but `%` to `z`. Then I enter a loop. `s/(z*)%/\10 z\1/` changes the first `%` to `0`, copies zero or more `z` from left to right, and adds one more `z` to right. This is so the number of `z` will equal the index. For example, `zz%zzz%...` becomes `zz0 zzzzzzzz%...` because the first `%` was at index 2, and the next `%` is at index 8. `s/z*$//` removes extra `z` from the end of the string.

The next eleven commands count `z` by removing each `z` and counting up from `0`. It counts like `zzz0`, `zz1`, `z2`, `3`. Also, `1zzzz9` becomes `z1zzz0` (later `23`), or `zzzz9` becomes `1zzz0` (later `13`). This loop continues until there are no more `%` or `z`.

Comment: +1 for teaching sed to count. It is easier to teach a llama to count than sed.

Answer (score 9):

### Fortran - <s>154</s> 148

Fortran sucks at golfing, but just to prove that parsing strings can be done in a math-based language, I did it:

```
function f result(r);integer::r(5),j=1;do i=1,len(s);if(s(i:i)==a(j:j).or.s(i:i)==b(j:j)) then;r(j)=i;j=j+1;endif;enddo;if(any(r==0))r=0;endfunction
```

I saved a few characters by eliminating the not-required `f` at the end of `endfunction` and used `if(any(r==0))` instead of `if(.not.all(r>0))`.

This requires:

1. `s` to be the string with text
2. `a` to be the lower-case test (i.e., `llama`)
3. `b` to be the upper-case test (i.e., `LLAMA`)

The full, un-golfed program is

```
program find_llama
   character(len=123) :: s = "Pie is good.  I just ate a bunch of pies early this morning.  Actually, it was closer to the afternoon.  Mornings are good."
   character(len=5) :: a="llama",b="LLAMA"

   print *,f()
 contains
   function f result(r)
     integer::r(5),j=1
     do i=1,len(s)
        if(s(i:i)==a(j:j).or.s(i:i)==b(j:j)) then
           r(j)=i
           j=j+1
        endif
     enddo
     if(any(r==0)) r=0
   end function
end program find_llama
```

Comment: Modern Fortran is at least allowed on the pitch & putt areas. FORTRAN IV would still be playing crazy golf.

Comment: @ClickRick: Fortran IV is something I have not learned. Not sure that I want to. Something about forced indentation and capitalization disturbs me.

Answer (score 8):

## Ruby, <s>56</s> <s>65</s> 63

**Edit**: +9 characters so that it is case-insensitive.

Defines a function (lambda, technically) `f`.

```
f=->s{i=0;'LLAMA'.chars.map{|c|i=s.upcase.index(c,i+1)||break}}
```

Returns `nil` if there is no llama. If it has to be `[]` (empty array), then just add `||[]` before the last `}` for a total of **4 extra** characters.

Readable version:

```
innerLlama = -> str{
    index = 0;
    str.downcase!
    arr = 'llama'.each_char.map{|char|
        index = str.index(char, index + 1)
        break unless index
    }
    # uncomment this line for empty array on failure
    #arr || []
}
```

Comment: I apologize for editing my question after some time, but I just added that the array, if no llama, can be nil,null,empty, or undefined.

Comment: So you did it with a llambda?

Comment: @Doorknob would be two bytes shorter by using upcase instead of downcase no?

Comment: @dstarh Yep, thanks

Comment: Think you can get case-insensitivity a byte cheaper by doing `index(/#{c}/i` instead of `upcase`.

Comment: This answer fails if the first l of 'llama' is at index 0. One fix is to change `i=0` to `i=-1`, but this costs 1 character. A different fix is to change `,i+1)` to `i)+1`, which causes it to count from 1, but costs nothing.

Answer (score 7):

### C# - 119

Takes string, outputs array. Null if no llama in string.

```
int[]a(string s){var i=0;var o="llama".Select((x,y)=>i=s.IndexOf(x,y>0?i+1:0));return o.All(x=>x>=0)?o.ToArray():null;}
```

Comment: I am impressed.  Way smaller than any of my ideas for this one.  I did find you could make it smaller by initializing `i` to -1 and putting the .ToArray() on the .Select statement, like so `int[]a(string s){var i=-1;var o="llama".Select(x=>i=s.IndexOf(x,i+1)).ToArray();return o.All(x=>x>=0)?o:null;}`

Answer (score 6):

## C - 53

Compile with:

```
gcc -D L=\"llama\" -D W=\"Lie\ is\ good.\ \ I\ just\ ate\ a\ bunch\ of\ pies\ early\ this\ morning.\ \ Actually,\ it\ was\ closer\ to\ the\ afternoon.\ \ Mornings\ are\ good.\"
```

I tested this compile command with cygwin's gcc. Other environments might handle spaces, and other special characters differently.

The 0-based result is stored into array `r`. Its contents are undefined if there is no llama in the string.

- Case-sensitive (53)

  `i,m,r[5];main(){for(;W[i];i++)W[i]==L[m]?r[m++]=i:i;}`
- Case-insensitive (58)

  `i,m,r[5];main(){for(;W[i];i++)(W[i]|96)==L[m]?r[m++]=i:i;}`

Answer (score 4):

## Python, 100

I am the worst golfer ever. :P

Thanks to @xnor for shaving off 6 bytes.

```
g,n,o='llama',0,[]
for i in s:
 if g:exec("o+=[n];g=g[1:];"*(i.lower()==g[0])+"n+=1")
o*=len(o)>4
```

`o` contains the array after.

**EDIT**: Fixed.

**EDIT 2**: `len(g)` to `g`, `o==5` to `o>4` as per @xnor's suggestions.

**EDIT 3**: @WolframH fixed it.

Comment: `o*=(len(o)==5)` is *excellent*. It's horrible, but I love it!

Comment: I don't think the outer parentheses on that line are necessary. You could save two characters by removing them.

Comment: @user2357112 On that second last line? I'll remove 'em.

Comment: I assume `s` is the input string, right? Shouldn't then `s.lower` be `i.lower`? However, that doe

Comment: @WolframH ah, yes, will fix tomorrow.

Comment: that comment should have been: I assume `s` is the input string, right? Shouldn't then `s.lower` be `i.lower`? However, that doesn't work, because after exhaustion of `g` accessing `g[0]` is an `IndexError`. Try replacing the first `+` with `or`, maybe that helps.

Comment: @WolframH Fixed it :D And it's 8 characters shorter!

Comment: You can shorter `if len(g)` to `if g` (Python treats the empty string/list as False) and `o*=len(o)==5` to `o*=len(o)>4`

Comment: @xnor Thanks :D Editing now.

Comment: `if lg:` is probably meant to be `if g:`. Could you move the `if g:` into the `exec()` and then put the `exec` on the same line as the `for` loop?

Comment: @WolframH The first is correct, I've tried the second one but with the only way I know to get it to work, it's longer.

Comment: @WolframH Thanks for the input/fixing/golfing btw ;D

Answer (score 3):

### Python 71

Assumes input in `s`. Output in `o`.

```python
F=s.lower().find
o=F('l'),
for c in'lama':o+=F(c,o[-1]+1),
o*=min(o)>=0
```

**Edit:** Changed from lists to tuples to save 2 bytes.

Comment: Multiplying lists by booleans is fun, isn't it? ;D

Comment: I like how you dodge the problem of `o` needing to start nonempty to take `o[-1]`. Maybe it's shorter though to just start `o` as `[-1]` and later do `o=o[1:]`? Annoyingly, the initial `-1` trips up checking if `o` contains `-1`.

Comment: @xnor: I don't think the `-1`-Idea can be made to work. At least, I didn't succeed :-( However, I changed lists to tuples to save 2 bytes. :-)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ECMAScript 6) - 68 Characters

```
(/((((.*l).*l).*a).*m).*a/.exec(s)||[]).map(x=>x.length-1).reverse()
```

Assumes that the string to test is in the variable `s`. If you want to turn it into a function then prepend `f=s=>` (for an additional 5 characters).

**Outputs:**

```
[]
```

**Case Insensitive - 69 Characters**

```
(/((((.*l).*l).*a).*m).*a/i.exec(s)||[]).map(x=>x.length-1).reverse()
```

**Outputs:**

```
[68, 80, 93, 105, 114]
```

**Case Insensitive & First Match - 74 Characters**

```
(/((((.*?l).*?l).*?a).*?m).*?a/i.exec(s)||[]).map(x=>x.length-1).reverse()
```

**Outputs:**

```
[44, 67, 76, 105, 114]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 100

```
import re
x=input()
print[re.search(r"l.*?(l).*?(a).*?(m).*?(a)",x,re.I).start(i) for i in range(5)]
```

Sample:

```
in  = Pie is good.  I just ate a bunch of pies early this morning.  Actually, it was closer to the afternoon.  Mornings are good.
out = [44, 67, 76, 105, 114]
in[out] = ['l', 'l', 'a', 'M', 'a']
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 111

```
import Data.Char
l i(a:as)t@(b:bs)|a==b=i:l(i+1)as bs|True=l(i+1)as t
l _ _ _=[]
r s=l 0(map toUpper s)"LLAMA"
```

Ungolfed:

```
import Data.Char

llama :: Int -> String -> String -> [Int]
llama i (a:as) t@(b:bs)
  | a==b      = i : llama (i+1) as bs
  | otherwise = llama (i+1) as t
llama _ _ _ = []

runme :: String -> [Int]
runme s = llama 0 (map toUpper s) "LLAMA"
```

Example:

```
*Main> r "Pie is good.  I just ate a bunch of pies early this morning.  Actually, it was closer to the afternoon.  Mornings are good."
[44,67,76,105,114]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Matlab, 61 <s>96</s>

Searches the string and replaces everything up to each match with gibberish before searching for next character. Will leave `s` undefined if an the word does not occur.

```
t='llama';for q=1:5;s(q)=min(regexpi(z,t(q))),z(1:s(q))=0;end
```

Note that the charcount could be reduced if case sensitivity is allowed.

**Previous versions**

```
 try;t='llama';for q=1:length(t);s(q)=find(lower(z)==t(q),1);z(1:s(q))=ones(1,s(q));end;catch;end
```

Searches the string and replaces everything up to each match with gibberish before searching for next character. Error handling (try-catch-end) could maybe be dropped, then the program would crash (but s would be undefined as required) if llama not found.

Implementation:

```
>> z='Pie is good.  I just ate a bunch of pies early this morning.  Actually, it was closer to the afternoon.  Mornings are good.';
>> try;t='llama';for q=1:length(t);s(q)=find(lower(z)==t(q),1);z(1:s(q))=ones(1,s(q));end;catch;end
>> s
s =

    45    68    77   106   115
```

Without error handling:

```
t='llama';for q=1:length(t);s(q)=find(lower(z)==t(q),1);z(1:s(q))=ones(1,s(q));end
```

Comment: Like the idea, have reduced charcount a bit.

Answer (score 2):

**Language Java**

```
 final int[] wordIndexInSentence(String sentence, String word)
  {
    final int[] returnArr = new int[word.length()];
    int fromIndex = 0;
    word = word.toUpperCase();
    sentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
      final char c = word.charAt(i);
      returnArr[i] = sentence.indexOf(c, fromIndex);
      fromIndex = returnArr[i] > 0 ? returnArr[i] + 1 : fromIndex;
    }
    return returnArr;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

## Rebol, 97

```
f: func[s][a: copy[]foreach n"llama"[if none? s: find s n[return[]]append a index? s s: next s]a]
```

Usage example in Rebol console:

```
>> f "Pie is good.  I just ate a bunch of pies early this morning.  Actually, it was closer to the afternoon.  Mornings are good." 
== [45 68 77 106 115]

>> f "nearly llami"       
== []

>> f "Llama"
== [1 2 3 4 5]

>> f reverse "llama"
== []
```

Rebol uses 1-based indexing.  Returns empty list `[]` if no llama sequence found (case insensitive).

Ungolfed:

```
f: func [s] [
    a: copy []
    foreach n "llama" [
        if none? s: find s n [return []]
        append a index? s
        s: next s
    ]
    a
]
```

Answer (score 2):

## OpenEuphoria, <strike>147</strike>128

I have two examples. First, the shortest:

```
object t=and_bits(gets(0),#DF),L="LLAMA",i=0,X={}for j=1 to 5 do 
i=find(L[j],t,i+1)X&=i 
end for 
if find(0,X) then X={} end if?X
```

I can get it down to 126 characters if I use "or" instead of "and" like the C version does up above. However, this also matches the string `''!-!` as `llama`. Uncommon, but still a possible error.

```
object t=or_bits(gets(0),96),L="llama",i=0,X={}for j=1 to 5 do 
i=find(L[j],t,i+1)X&=i 
end for 
if find(0,X) then X={} end if?X
```

And then the version using regular expressions:

```
include std/regex.e
include std/sequence.e
include std/utils.e
object X=regex:find(new("(?i)(l).*?(l).*?(a).*?(m).*?(a)"),gets(0))
? iff(atom(X),{},vslice(X[2..6],2))
```

Both take input from STDIN and post to STDOUT.

EDIT: Shorter regex example:

```
include std/regex.e
include std/sequence.e
object X=regex:find(new("(?i)(l).*?(l).*?(a).*?(m).*?(a)"),gets(0))
if atom(X)then?{}else?vslice(X[2..6],2)end if
```

Comment: Is it possible to save a few by building the regex with `split`/`join` or `explode`/`implode`, or does OpenEuphoria not have short versions of those?

Comment: OpenEuphoria can do split/join with strings of characters, but I don't see a way to do it in a shorter manner. I'm not very good with regular expressions; the regex used here was "inspired" (shamelessly stolen) from one of the other examples on this page.

Answer (score 2):

## Python (70)

```python
r=[];c=-1
for x in'llama':c=s.lower().find(x,c+1);r+=[c]
r*=1-(-1in r)
```

We search of each character in `'llama'` in turn, starting after the location of the previously-found character. If no character is found, `c` becomes the default value of `-1`, in which case the last line turns `r` into the empty list.

Edit: Found out that `str.find(s,...)` can be invoked as `s.find(...)`, saving 4 characters.

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell - <del>121</del> 85

I'm still practicing with Powershell, expect this could be improved

$s contains the string, result is in array $a

Original version

```
$a=@();$w="llama";$n=$c=0;foreach ($i in $s.tochararray()) {if ($i -eq $w[$n]) {$a+=$c;$n+=1} $c+=1};$a*=$a.length -gt 4
```

Ungolfed

```
$a=@()
$w="llama"
$n=$c=0
foreach ($i in $s.tochararray()) {
 if ($i -eq $w[$n]) {
  $a+=$c
  $n+=1
 } $c+=1
}
$a*=$a.length -gt 4
```

New version, with massive thanks to @goric

```
$a=@();$n=$c=0;[char[]]$s|%{if($_-eq"llama"[$n]){$a+=$c;$n++}$c++};$a*=$a.length-gt4
```

Comment: You can remove a lot of spaces in there to shorten things up to 112: `$a=@();$w="llama";$n=$c=0;foreach($i in $s.tochararray()){if($i-eq$w[$n]){$a+=$c;$n+=1}$c+=1};$a*=$a.length-gt4`

Comment: Also, you can replace `foreach($i in $s.tochararray())` with `[char[]]$s|%`, as long as you change the subsequent `$i` to a `$_`. That shaves it down to 93: `$a=@();$w="llama";$n=$c=0;[char[]]$s|%{if($_-eq$w[$n]){$a+=$c;$n+=1}$c+=1};$a*=$a.length-gt4`

Comment: Save 5 more chars by removing the `$w` variable altogether, since its only used once. Just inline it into the if: `if($i-eq"llama"[$n])`

Comment: ..and, of course, replace your `+=1`s with `++`s

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
ŒlẹⱮ“ṫɠ»Ż>ƇḢ¥@\Ḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc0xCsIwGMXxq7wDiEcQHR0ED@AS69c2JSaSpIibW8Gxk4ODCE6C4NbarVLBY6QXiYHuv/f@GQlx8L4rhXvX/evZHy@ufvyubdM1k2/hqlt7n65cdfKfoitdffZ@yQncIFFqMwbmyHJjwSyBYZ3LKIWKseNkQEyLA2wa8FZpyWUS/CyyOQvNEbjFnhlEQhnSsCrI8BFb0lIpGehiGBkwTUPuDw)

### How it works

```
ŒlẹⱮ“ṫɠ»Ż>ƇḢ¥@\Ḋ - Main link. Takes a string on the left
Œl               - Lowercase
    “ṫɠ»         - Compressed string: "llama"
   Ɱ             - For each character in "llama":
  ẹ              -   Find the indexes of that character in the input
        Ż        - Prepend 0
            ¥    - Last 2 links as a dyad f(x, y):
         >Ƈ      -   Keep elements of x greater than y
           Ḣ     -   Take the first element
             @\  - Reduce the list by the f(y, x)
               Ḋ - Dequeue
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP

no PHP answer yet? I think a language heavily string-oriented can beat at least a math-based one

```
function x($s){$i=$j=0;$r=str_split('llama');$s=strtolower($s);while($i<strlen($s)){if($s[$i]==$r[$j]){$r[$j]=$i;$j++;if($j>4)return$r;}$i++;}return[];}
```

152 against fortran 154, job done :P

ungolfed

```
function x($s){
    $i=$j=0;$r=str_split('llama');
    $s=strtolower($s);
    while($i<strlen($s)){
        if ($s[$i]==$r[$j]){
            $r[$j]=$i;
            $j++;
            if($j>4)
                return $r;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return[];
}
```

if the caller always passes a lowercase string, it lowers to 137

Comment: You need to add `<?` at the beginning of your code to make it valid. Sorry...

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <strike>122</strike> 115

```
function(s,b){z=[];for(i=0;i<5;i++){z.push(b=s.toLowerCase().indexOf("llama"[i],++b))};return z.indexOf(-1)<0?z:[]}
```

Defines a function that takes a string as its only argument (second arg is a cheap `var`) and returns either an empty array or a 5-element array.

Drops to 108 if I take the input on a single char variable (`s`) and leave the output in another (`b`):

```
var b=((z="llama".split('').map(function(a){return (b=s.toLowerCase().indexOf(a,++b))})).indexOf(-1)<0?z:[])
```

Edit: Swapped out map for for loop.

Comment: ECMAScript 6 version (81 characters) - `b=(z=[].map.call("llama",a=>b=s.toLowerCase().indexOf(a,++b))).indexOf(-1)<0?z:[]`

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 47

```
+\↑⊃{a s←⍵⋄~⍺∊s:⍬⍬⋄a,←n←s⍳⍺⋄a(n↓s)}/'amall',⊂⍬⍞
```

Not the shortest code, but quite warped, in an APL way.

**Explanation**

`'amall',⊂⍬⍞`   Make an array of 6 elements: the letters 'amall' and a subarray of 2 elements, themselves subarrays: the empty array and a line of characters read from input.

`{...}/...` Reduce (right-fold) the 6-element array using the provided function.

`a s←⍵`     Decompose the right argument into the array of indices and the remaining substring (initially the empty array and the full string.)

`~⍺∊s:⍬⍬`   If the substring does not contain the next letter `⍺` stop the computation and return the empty array.

`a,←n←s⍳⍺`  Otherwise, find its position, call it n, and append it to the array of indices.

`a(n↓s)`    Make and return an array of 2 elements: the extended array of indices and the remaining substring.

`+\↑⊃...`   Unpack the output of the folding, take the first element (the array of indices) and scan it with addition, to turn relative offsets into absolute ones.

**Examples**

```
      +\↑⊃{a s←⍵⋄~⍺∊s:⍬⍬⋄a,←n←s⍳⍺⋄a(n↓s)}/'amall',⊂⍬⍞
All cats meow aloud.
2 3 6 10 15
```

```
      +\↑⊃{a s←⍵⋄~⍺∊s:⍬⍬⋄a,←n←s⍳⍺⋄a(n↓s)}/'amall',⊂⍬⍞
Some cats purr instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 76

Another regex example using Julia language.

```
f(s)=(m=match(r"(?i)(l).*?(l).*?(a).*?(m).*?(a)",s);m==nothing?m:m.offsets)
```

Answer (score 0):

## ARM Thumb-2 machine code, 42 bytes

Machine code (little endian hexdump):

```
2500 a208 f812 3b01 b15b 5d44 b144 3501
42a3 d003 f084 0420 42a3 d1f6 c120 e7f1
2100 4770 6c6c 6d61 0061
```

Commented assembly:

```java
        .syntax unified
        .arch armv6t2
        .thumb
        .globl llama
        .thumb_func
        // Input:
        //    r0: null terminated string
        //    r1: output uint32_t array, must be 4 byte aligned
        // Output:
        //    if it matches, the ONE-INDEXED offsets are stored in r1
        //    otherwise, r1 is set to NULL. (Elements are still
        //    modified).
llama:
        // index
        movs    r5, #0
        // lookup table
        adr     r2, .LLAMA
        // loop through "llama"
.Llama:
        // Read byte from llama string, increment
        ldrb    r3, [r2], #1
        // end at null terminator
        cbz     r3, .LlAmA
.LLama:
        // r4 = str[r5]
        ldrb    r4, [r0, r5]
        // if we reach the null terminator, we don't have a match.
        cbz     r4, .LlaMa
        // increment r5 (this is what makes it one indexed)
        adds    r5, #1
        // check for a direct match
        cmp     r3, r4
        beq     .LLAma
        // flip the case by xoring 1<<5
        eor     r4, r4, #0b00100000
        // test the case when flipped
        cmp     r3, r4
        bne     .LLama
.LLAma:
        // *r1++ = index
        stm     r1!, {r5}
        // loop indefinitely (trip condition is the first cbz)
        b       .Llama
.LlaMa:
        // If we don't have a match, set r1 to NULL.
        movs    r1, #0
.LlAmA:
        // Otherwise, return.
        bx      lr
.LLAMA:
        .asciz  "llama"
```